# React Native : How to avoid build error on different local environment over time

Tags: android, ios, react-native, build

I'm in a company, and we have a lot of build problems when we put a new developper on an existing react native projects. We all know that it can take hours or even days before he start to work.

We use fastlane and jenkins for deployment but we dont use anything for the local aspect (exept yarn/npm of course).

I guess those problems are caused by different version of build tool (cacoapod, gradle, react-native-cli ...) or different environments (even if we're all working on macos).

I was wondering if any of you have faced some similar situations and if you have some tips.

Maybe something like a "build server" can exist, or tools to automate build tool installation / setup with given versions (something like a package.json for build tools). Or other things that can help us.

A brief list of things that i often face:

- Android: impossible to run anything via react-native command (no real debogger) Activity is not found
- iOS: The app launch and close a little time during splashscreen
- fastlane iOS: The build is working sometimes but it is really fortunate. It says that there are multiple reference to *.a files.

But my collegues face other problems. Our goal is to find a solution that can live over time. Like what a well configured docker can do with web project.

Comment: I don't think that is the good place for this generic question. [Stackoverflow is for specific programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) could be more appropriate.